# Javascript function returns undefined error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

In my Cordova android app i am using `getDeviceId` function to get the unique device id.

```
function getDeviceId(){
        var temp;   
        newid=cordova.require('org.apache.cordova.uuid.UniqueDeviceID');
            newid.getDeviceID(success,fail);
            function  success(uuid){
              //this works 
              alert("inside function"+uuid);
              temp=uuid;
            }
            function fail(err){
             // alert("error"+err);
             }
           return temp;
        }
```

And i am calling this function like this way

```
var deviceId=getDeviceId();
//undefined error
alert("from function"+deviceId);
```

I will get device-id successfully inside the function,but the return value  will give undefined error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use promise!

## Short answer:

```
function getDeviceId(success, fail){
    return cordova.require('org.apache.cordova.uuid.UniqueDeviceID').getDeviceID(success, fail);
}
```

## Better answer:

```
function getDeviceId(){
    var temp; //assume this as cache, this must be outside of this function scope, but for the sake of example
    var defer = q.defer(); //or any other promise libraries
    if(!temp){
        var cordova = cordova.require('org.apache.cordova.uuid.UniqueDeviceID');
        cordova.getDeviceID(function(uuid){
            temp = uuid;
            defer.resolve(uuid); //or other api depend on library
         }, function(err){
            temp = null; //clear cache on errors
            defer.reject('Could not get device id');
         });
    } else {
        defer.resolve(temp);
    }
    return defer.promise; //or other api depend on library   
}
```

## Specific answer to  you:

```
function getDeviceId(success, fail){
    return cordova.require('org.apache.cordova.uuid.UniqueDeviceID').getDeviceID(success, fail);
}
```

and then

```
getDeviceId(function(uuid){
    console.log(uuid); //this might be object, so drill to specific field
    alert("from function" + uuid);
}, function(errorMessage){
    alert(errorMessage);
});
```

## Advice:

Checkout greate article about [promises in details](http://dailyjs.com/2014/02/20/promises-in-detail/)

Comment: no, you are returning var `temp` which is undefined, it will be defined when success callback called, but that temp returned immediately, so obviously it will be always undefined

Comment: you need to pass function to `var deviceId=getDeviceId();`

Comment: Your specfic answer work partially but the `temp` variable returns undefined error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84763/discussion-between-evc-and-shammon).